# Sedra and Smith - Common-mode input resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis

In Sedra and Smith it is stated that the common-mode input resistance of a differential amplifier is:

[image]

From the diagram(s):

[image]

It is stated in the book they have used the diagram on the right (equivalent common-mode half circuit) to prove 2R<sub>icm</sub>.

I've tried to prove this, and I've gotten about half of the equation, with the other half being a function of r<sub>EE</sub> (which is not in their answer). Would anybody be able to help me prove this and show the steps involved?

Comment: This is on page 636, Figure 9.27, 7th Edition for anyone who wants to look up any background context.

Comment: Please share your steps so far.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? (It sound like it.) Either way, you should always post what you have already done.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you would draw the small-signal schematic and solve for the input impedance using regular KCL/KVL equations.

But looking at the shape of the equation, I'd say they used Middlebrook's Extra-Element Theorem on \$r_0\$. In other words, you first determine the input impedance of the following circuit without \$r_0\$ (ie. \$r_0 \to \infty\$).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2qt4G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$Z_{in}^\infty = 2R_{icm}^\infty = \frac{V}{i_B}$$

$$\begin{align}
i_B &= \frac{V}{2R_{EE}} - \beta i_B \\
&\Downarrow \\
i_B &= \frac{V}{(1+\beta) 2R_{EE}}\approx\frac{V}{2\beta R_{EE}} \\
&\Downarrow \\
R_{icm}^\infty &\approx \beta R_{EE}
\end{align}$$

We can find the driving point impedances in a relatively simple way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK19bh.png)</sup>

$$\begin{align}
Z_n &= \frac{R_C}{1+\beta} \approx \frac{R_C}{\beta} \\
Z_d &= R_C + 2R_EE \\
R_{icm} &= R_{icm}^\infty\frac{1 + \frac{Z_n}{r_0}}{1 + \frac{Z_d}{r_0}}
&\Downarrow \\
R_{icm} &\approx \beta R_{EE}\frac{1 + \frac{R_C}{\beta r_0}}{1 + \frac{R_C + 2R_{EE}}{r_0}}
\end{align}$$